# Transmission coefficient in microwave cavities

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, microwaves

I have a trouble finding the transmission coefficient S in the given case below.
[image: Magnetic film in a planar microwave cavity]

I am an undergraduate student and this is an exercise handed to me by my supervisor, which I haven't yet to get around for quite some time. The paper give the details of the wave functions in each region, given below.

[image: Wave functions of incident microwaves in each region]

The transmission coefficient is obtained through electromagnetic boundary conditions of continuity, and as given by the paper it's expressed as

[image: The transmission coefficient, given by the paper]

The paper can be found here, DOI: 10.1103/PhysRevB.91.094423

I've tried applying the boundary condition just like what the paper tells me. However, I am left with this expression

[image: The transmission coefficient that I found]

The problem is I still don't see any way to manipulate my expression into the one given by the paper. My supervisor couldn't come up with better hints that could help me sort this out. Please help. Any kind of input is appreciated. Thank you. :))